# Some questions about the proof of the third Sylow theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, sylow-theory

3. Sylow's Theorem: Let $|G| = p^n · m$ with $p$ prime, m coprime to $p$, and $n ≥ 1$. The number $α(p)$ of $p$-Sylow groups of $G$ is a divisor of $m$ and of the form $α(p) = 1+kp$ for a $k ≥ 0$.

Proof:

Let $S$ be the set of all $p$-Sylow groups of $G$. $G$ operates on this through conjugation. By Sylow's 2nd theorem we have a single $G$ orbit and $S =\{ gP g^{−1}
| g ∈ G \}$. $α(p) = [G : St_G(P)]$ a divisor of $m$. The group $P$ also operates on $S$ by conjugation.

Let $Q ∈ S$ be an element of the fixed point set $S^P$ . It follows $P ⊆ Q$ (1), and because of equality of numbers even $P = Q$. So $P$ is the only fixed point of this $P$ action. This results in $α(p) = |S | = 1 + kp$ for a $k ≥ 0$. (2)

(1) and (2): Why? I didn't understand these two steps

Comment: For a `proof-explanation` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof needs explanation, and *why so*.

Comment: Didn't they *precisely* do, @BillDubuque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1):
\begin{equation*}
S^P\overset{\rm def}{=} \{A\in S:\ gAg^{-1}=A,\ \text{for all $g\in P$}\}.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, if $Q\in S^P$, then $gQg^{-1}=Q$ for all $x\in P$.
Therefore $P\subseteq N_G(Q)$ by the definition of normalizer.
Since $Q\subseteq N_G(Q)\subseteq G$, $|N_G(Q)|=p^nm_0$ for some $m_0\mid m$.
Therefore $P,Q$ are both Sylow-$p$ subgroups of $N_G(Q)$.
Since $Q$ is normal in $N_G(Q)$ (by the definition of normalizer again) and $P,Q$  are conjugate *in* $N_G(Q)$, by applying the second Sylow theorem *to* $N_G(Q)$ we have $P=Q$.

(2)
\begin{equation*}
|S|=\sum_{\text{$\Lambda$ is an orbit}} \Lambda.
\end{equation*}
The above argument shows that $\{P\}$ is the only orbit with one element.
Any other orbit $\Lambda$ has $\frac{|P|}{|{\rm Stab}(x)|}$ elements where $x$ is an element in $\Lambda$, which is a multiple of $p$ since $|P|=p^n$ and $|\Lambda|\ne 1$